# org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: throw while unmarshalling the bindy bean

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-http

I'm trying to make a api call and get payload and enrich the content after unmarshalling the bean object. I can see that unmarshalling the bindy object has been happened but, it is throwing the below exception after making api call.

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://inbox?fileName=3100.txt                                                ] [         4]
[route1            ] [unmarshal1        ] [unmarshal[org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition@6e255e77]               ] [         0]
[route1            ] [enrich1           ] [enrich[constant{direct:getUN}]                                                ] [         0]
[route2            ] [setHeader1        ] [setHeader[CamelHttpMethod]                                                    ] [         0]
[route2            ] [setHeader2        ] [setHeader[Content-Type]                                                       ] [         0]
[route2            ] [to2               ] [http://localhost:8084/get/45718                                               ] [         1]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: PART_INB_IFD(ctrl_seg=CTRL_SEG(TRNNAM=PART_TRAN, TRNVER=9.0, WHSE_ID=----, PART_SEG=PART_SEG(SEGNAM=PART, TRNTYP=R, PRT_CLIENT_ID=----, PRTNUM=598, HAZMAT_FLG=1, VC_TOSG_HAZ_UN_NUM=null))) of type: com.model.PART_INB_IFD on: Message[]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type:
```

**ConverterRoute.java**

```
@Override
    public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                try {

                    XmlFriendlyNameCoder nameCoder = new XmlFriendlyNameCoder("_-", "_");
                    Dom4JDriver dom4JDriver = new Dom4JDriver(nameCoder);

                    xStreamDataFormat.setAliases(Collections.singletonMap("PART_INB_IFD", PART_INB_IFD.class.getCanonicalName()));
                    xStreamDataFormat.setXstreamDriver(dom4JDriver);

                    from(SOURCE_INPUT_PATH).
                            log("Received input from file and body is ${body}").
                            split().tokenize(System.lineSeparator()).
                            unmarshal(bindyBeanConfig.bindyCsvDataFormat()).
                            enrich("direct:getUN", new MyProcessor()).
                            marshal(xStreamDataFormat).
                            log("After Marshalling and body is ${body}").
                            to(SOURCE_OUTPUT_PATH).log("Finished Transformation").
                            end();

                    from("direct:getUN")
                            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,constant("GET"))
                            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                            .to("http://localhost:8084/get/45718")
                            .log("HTTP response status: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}")
                            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "HTTP response body:\n${body}");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        context.suspend();
        context.stop();
    }
```

Below I have implemented the aggregation strategy. Which will gets the oldExchange after unmarshalling newExchange the payload which api is returning.

**MyProcessor.java**

```
   public class MyProcessor implements AggregationStrategy {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyProcessor.class);

        @Override
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

            PART_INB_IFD originalBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(PART_INB_IFD.class);

            String resourceResponse = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

            logger.info("After Unmarshalling Original Body {}", originalBody);

            logger.info("ResourceResponse {}", resourceResponse);

            return oldExchange;
        }
    }
```